# Converting python itertools combinations into parallel programming for server

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I created a function to calculate a similarity score for a combination of all possible pair form a huge list which has almost 100000 items in the list which will take billions of possible unique combinations. I have access to a server which has specs with 256 GB RAM with 192 CPUs. How can I convert my code into a parallel version to use multi-processor?

```py
def calculate_cn(g, current_year, beta):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['source', 'target', 'cn_count', 'cn_value'])
    for comb in combinations(g.nodes, 2):
        cn_list = nx.common_neighbors(g, comb[0], comb[1])
        number_common = sorted(cn_list)

        if len(number_common) > 0:
            for c in number_common:
                from_source = g.get_edge_data(comb[0], c)
                first_value = 0.0

                for s in from_source:
                    first_value += from_source[s]['weight'] - beta*(current_year - from_source[s]['year'])


                from_target = g.get_edge_data(c, comb[1])

                for s in from_target:
                    first_value += from_target[s]['weight'] - beta * (current_year - from_target[s]['year'])


                df = df.append({'source': comb[0], 'target': comb[1], 'cn_count':len(number_common),
                                'cn_value': first_value
                                }, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            df = df.append({'source': comb[0], 'target': comb[1], 'cn_count': len(number_common),
                            'cn_value': 0}, ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

Comment: before even beginning to parallelize things, start by using efficient algorithms. `df = df.append(` is horribly inefficient. don't use that. create a list then call the dataframe constructor on that list.